# Managed metadata but cannot filter recursive

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I'm created a term set. But when I'm adding filter to a list. Some terms cannot filter recursive.

Please help me some suggestion for this issue.
I'm using sharepoint online 2013.

Conclusion: It seems to be inserted flow is incorrect.

Thanks,